# How to make a validation rule in laravel similar to if (condition 1) and (condition 2), true

Tags: laravel

I have the following validation rule in my controller

```
"holder_name" => 'required_if:paymentMethod,==,credit_card',
```

That is, if paymentMethod = credit_card then holder_name is required / mandatory.

Now I need one more condition to be checked.
I'll give the example as it would be in pure php, using if

For example I need to check if (paymentMethod = credit_card and card_id! = Null)

I already tried using two required_if:

```
'required_if:paymentMethod,==,credit_card'|'required_if:card_id,!=,null'
```

But it does not work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the following rule for your validation.

The `required_with` rule mandates a field if any of listed ones are non-empty.

```php
'required_if:paymentMethod,credit_card|required_with:card_id'
```